# Why is same return type but result is difference

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I have two function of same return type in java script but return type is difference. The using code of snipped id below

```
function foo1()
    {
      return {
          bar: "hello"
      };
    }

    function foo2()
    {
      return
      {
          bar: "hello"
      };
    }
```

calling the function..

```
console.log("foo1 returns:");
console.log(foo1());
console.log("foo2 returns:");
console.log(foo2());
```

Output the result ....

```
foo1 returns:
Object {bar: "hello"}
foo2 returns:
undefined
```

Comment: can you provide full code instead of small part ?

Comment: @Darshit That is the full code.

Comment: @Konst Please don't suggest edits in code like that unless you're fully aware of all the ramifications - the changes you've made will cause the problem to disappear.

Comment: Yes @JamesThorpe may be issues regarding ASI. This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 7):

Its automatic insert of the semicolon here. The rest of code is never reached.

```
function foo2()
{
  return    // get a automatic semicolon insert here
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}
```

Please have a look: [Warning: unreachable code after return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return)

Answer (score 7):

That's because JavaScript interprets

```
return
{
    bar: "hello"
};
```

as `return` statement followed by block creation (which is ignored in runtime). Not as "return an object". And I really don't know why JavaScript devs made such decision.

Anyway ASI inserts `;` after `return` resulting in the equivalent code:

```
return;
{
    bar: "hello"
};
```

The newline after `return` is the culprit. Don't use it if you wish to return something.

Answer (score 1):

A javascript free you do without semicolon but it puts a automatic semicolon, that is why you get undefined [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

```
function foo1()
    {
      return {
          bar: "hello"
      };
    }

    function foo2()
    {
      return{
          bar: "hello"
      };
    }
    console.log("foo1 returns:");
    console.log(foo1());
    console.log("foo2 returns:");
    console.log(foo2());
```